# How to make acetic acid from 2-methylpropan-2-ol?

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism

How to make acetic acid from 2-methylpropan-2-ol? I tried oxidation but it didn't work.

Comment: Hi neel gohil! Take a [tour] to know about this community!

Comment: Welcome to Chem.SE! We require you to show your efforts on this problem. What formulae/steps did you try? Please add this to your question. Thanks!

Comment: I made alken from the reactant and then I am confused.

Answer (score 1):

First dehydrate the given tert-butanol to form 2-methyl prop-1-ene. Then do reductive ozonolysis and you will have acetone and formaldehyde. These two products can be easily separated if you treat the solution with Tollen's reagent. Thus formaldehyde will form formic acid and acetone will remain as it is.

Now if you pour this solution into a solution of polar basic solvent, the acetone will form a layer, which is easily separated, but formic acid will be easily soluble. Taking the acetone, you will get the acetic acid via the haloform reaction and then hydrolysing under acidic conditions.

Comment: If you like it , just upvote..